# SwiftUI: can I add on-init code to a view without overriding the default initializer?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm a very experienced programmer, but I'm completely new to Swift and SwiftUI. (I took a few of the intro courses in the Playgrounds app yesterday.)

The app I'm trying to write takes several length measurements as input, which is nontrivial, so I figured I should encapsulate that into its own view. Using [this answer][1] as inspiration, here's what I have so far:

```
struct LengthMeasurementField: View {
    var placeholder : String
    @Binding var binding : Measurement<UnitLength>
    @State var textValue = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        TextField(placeholder, text: $textValue)
            .fixedSize()
            .textFieldStyle(.roundedBorder)
            .onChange(of: textValue) { val in
            if let newValue = Double(val) {
                binding = Measurement(value: newValue, unit: UnitLength.inches)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Which I then use as follows:

```
HStack {
    Text("Diameter")
    LengthMeasurementField(placeholderText: "Diameter", binding: $inputs.diameter)
}
```

This renders, but if inputs.diameter already has a value when the view is first rendered, that value is ignored -- the UI renders with just the placeholder text. This is because `textValue` is initialized as empty string and only updated via onChange.

I'd like to have textValue initialize with the string-formatted value from the binding. I tried this:

```
init() {
    textValue = String(format: "%f", binding.value)
}
```

But, of course, that eliminates the default initializer, so now my usage breaks. I then tried implementing the default initializer explicitly, but it doesn't compile, I think something special is happening because of the @Binding:

```
    init(placeholder: String, binding: Measurement<UnitLength>) {
        self.placeholder = placeholder
        self.binding = binding // Variable 'self.binding' used before being initialized
        self.textValue = String(format: "%f", binding.value) // Variable 'self.binding' used before being initialized
    } // Return from initializer without initializing all stored properties
```

This raises a few questions:

1. Why doesn't it compile? How can I fix it?
2. Is there a way for me to provide some on-init code for my view while still having access to the default initializer?

Side note: I know that I could do all this much more easily if I didn't use Measurement, and just had a field with a formatted Double in it. I plan to make the unit selectable via a dropdown, and won't be hardcoding it to .inches in the long term, so I think my current approach is probably going to be worthwhile. If you know otherwise, or if there's some built-in thing that already does this somewhere, I'd appreciate any advice you might have!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer question 2 which kind of makes question irrelevant, you can use the view modifier `.onAppear` to set up `textValue` correctly in `LengthMeasurementField`

```
.onAppear {
    textValue = binding.formatted()
}
```

Comment: (Question 1 is still relevant for my learning; just not pertinent to this View. :) )

Answer (score 2):

Your overriding of the synthesized initializer is the correct approach. You've just defined the wrong parameter types:

```
init(placeholder: String, binding: Binding<Measurement<UnitLength>>) {
                                   ^^^^^^^
```

You can get Xcode to write this for you by right-clicking the struct name, and selecting "Show Code Actions> Generate Memberwise Initializer."

Comment: Thanks -- Generate Memberwise Initializer will be useful going forward! I have a lot to learn about Xcode. However, when I did that, it did not include `Binding` as you noted, and the generated initializer was nearly identical to the one I included in my question, except that it was prefixed with `internal`, which I had to look up.

Comment: Also, it seems like `onAppear` (Joakim's answer) is a more appropriate approach. It shows intent and requires less code. Do you disagree? If so, why?

Comment: `onAppear` is fine. It just happens later.